# Android cameraX

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Можно ли использовать cameraX в background services?
Нашёл пример с camera2 api, но не нашёл ничего подобного для cameraX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько явствует из документации [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax):

> it leverages the capabilities of camera2, it uses a simpler, use case-based approach that is lifecycle-aware.

Фактически это означает, что CameraX реализует функционал Camera2, соответственно код написанный для Camera2, должен работать под копи-пейст с CameraX (естественно, с учетом небольшого изменения названий методов/полей)

Comment: не получается из сервиса использовать cameraX, нашёл такую проблему [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401955/android-camerax-in-floating-widget-service)